# 4 level interdependent select lists ajax jquery json and mysql 

Tags: php, ajax

I have got it working up to the third select list. But there are 4.

country, source, target and subject.

I am able to select up to the target select list alright, but I can't make it to the final one, the subject. This is because I don't know how to complete the missing code for that one.

Here is the script and further below will be the processing one. So it is the 'subject' select list that needs to move accordingly to its next to the left:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#sel_pais").change(function () {
        //
        var datatosend = 'pais_id=' + jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'includes/getchilds2.php',
            data:datatosend,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function (data) {
                jQuery('#sel_source').find('option').remove().end();
                jQuery('#sel_target').find('option').remove().end();
                jQuery.each(data, function (index, val) {
                    var newopt = '<option value="' + val.key + '">' + val.title + '</option>';
                    jQuery('#sel_source').append(newopt);
                });
                jQuery('#sel_target').append('<option value="-1">Select</option>');

            }

        });
    });
    //////////////////////
    jQuery("#sel_source").change(function () {
        //
        var datatosend = 'id_from=' + jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'includes/getchilds2.php',
            data:datatosend,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function (data) {
                jQuery('#sel_target').find('option').remove().end();
                jQuery.each(data, function (index, val) {
                    var newopt = '<option value="' + val.key + '">' + val.title + '</option>';
                    jQuery('#sel_target').append(newopt);
                });
            }

        });
    });


});
```

And here is the processing one:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("traducteurs", $con);
//
if (isset($_GET['pais_id'])) {
    $curid = $_GET['pais_id'];
    //  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla_from where pais_id=" . $curid);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $op = '[';
        $op .= '{"title":"Select","key":"-1"},';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $op .= '{';
            $op .= '"title":"' . $row['from_name'] . '", "key":"' . $row['id_from'] . '"';
            $op .= '},';
        }
        $op = substr($op, 0, -1);
        $op .= ']';
        echo $op;
    }
    else {
        echo '[{"title":"Select","key":"-1"}]';
    }
}
/////////////////////
if (isset($_GET['id_from'])) {
    $curid = $_GET['id_from'];
    //  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla_into where id_from=" . $curid);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $op = '[';
        $op .= '{"title":"Select","key":"-1"},';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $op .= '{';
            $op .= '"title":"' . $row['into_language'] . '", "key":"' . $row['id_into'] . '"';
            $op .= '},';
        }
        $op = substr($op, 0, -1);
        $op .= ']';
        echo $op;
    }
    else {
        echo '[{"title":"Select","key":"-1"}]';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Please don't take it personally, it's an automated comment I immediately throw whenever I see `mysql_*` in a question. If you already aware that this code is horrible, than you've saved another kitten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this code to show interdependent list

```
<select id="sel_pais" name="sel_pais">
<option value="pais_id">values goes here</option>
</select>

<select id="sel_source" name="sel_source">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>

<select id="sel_target" name="sel_target">
<option value="">select</option>
</select>

<select id="sel_subject" name="sel_subject">
<option value="">select</option>
</select>
//jquery code for source list
$('#sel_pais').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val()!='') {
    $("#sel_source").load("include/getchild2.php",{pais_id: $(this).val()});
  }
});
//code on change of sel_source
$('#sel_source').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val()!='') {
    $("#sel_target").load("include/getchild2.php",{id_from: $(this).val()});
  }
});

$('#sel_target').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val()!='') {
    $("#sel_subject").load("include/getchild2.php",{id_target: $(this).val()});
  }
});
```

php sample code you can change.. repeat the below code for others.

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['pais_id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['pais_id'])) {
    $result = mysql_query("select * from table where id='".$_REQUEST['pais_id']."' "));
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo '<option value="">Select</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {              
                echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">Select</option>';
    }
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you very much, i am going to study it now. It will take me a while because I am new to it but I will come back with thanks and feedback. Regards

Comment: ok i have studied it. I like it because it is a much clearer code than the one I had. I am going to try it and will be back. for a start i give you the thanks as a useful answer and as i implement it will tell you if i managed to make it work. thank you very much!

Comment: are you using this specific class to connect to the db ezSQL / mysql / ez_sql_mysql.php?

Comment: I think there is a typo in $rowst where it should be $row

Comment: The jquery code is clear, but the mysql php i have tried all combinations, including that sql class i think you are using, then the procedural style, i am not getting any results starting on the second select list. I did fill the first one because it does not depend on others, i filled it just with the sql query, but after that, nothing :(

Comment: No, i am not getting it to work and it is not just the mysql query, because i dont get any result when doing echo $_REQUEST['pais_id] so it is not loading the processing script and the path to it is correct.

Comment: its bcz I am using another class for mysql stuff. I just updated d answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14200/discussion-between-iaintunderstand-and-shahid-ahmed)